# Avro DataFileReader needs a seekable file

Tags: python, python-3.x, avro

The problem is stdin doesn't support seek which is needed by avro, so we read everything to buffer and then giving this to avro_wrapper. It works in Python 2, but doesn't work in Python 3. I have tried a few solutions but none of them are working.

```
# stdin doesn't support seek which is needed by avro... so this hack worked in python 2. This does not work in Python 3. 
# Reading everything to buffer and then giving this to avro_wrapper. 
buf = StringIO()
buf.write(args.input_file.read())
r = DataFileReader(buf, DatumReader())
# Very first record the headers information. Which gives the header names in order along with munge header names for all the record types
# For e.g if we have 2 ports then it will hold the header information of
#   1. port1 on name1 key
#   2. port2 on name2 key and so on 
headers_record = next(r)['headers']
```

The above produces `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 17: invalid continuation byte` error.

We then tried doing it this way:

```
input_stream = io.TextIOWrapper(args.input_file.buffer, encoding='latin-1')
sio = io.StringIO(input_stream.read())
r = DataFileReader(sio, DatumReader())
headers_record = next(r)['headers']
```

This produces `avro.schema.AvroException: Not an Avro data file: Obj doesn't match b'Obj\x01'.` error.

Another way:

```
input_stream = io.TextIOWrapper(args.input_file.buffer, encoding='latin-1')
buf = io.BytesIO(input_stream.read().encode('latin-1'))
r = DataFileReader(buf.read(), DatumReader())
headers_record = next(r)['headers']
```

This produces `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'" error.`

Comment: Try using a binary file. Or use ascii encoding

Comment: Why did you *read* the `io.BytesIO()` buffer?

Comment: `stdin` isn't your problem; it's whatever `stdin` is *bound* to.

Comment: Also, what type of object does `args.input_file.read()` return on Python 3? Presumably `bytes`, or you'd have a different error when wrapping it in a `io.TextIOWrapper()` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`io.BytesIO()` is the correct type to use to create a seekable in-memory file object containing binary data.

However, you made the mistake of reading out the `bytes` data from your `io.BytesIO()` file object, and passing those in instead of the actual file object.

**Don't read**, pass in the actual `io.BytesIO` file object with the binary data read from `stdin`:

```
buf = io.BytesIO(args.input_file.buffer.read())
r = DataFileReader(buf, DatumReader())
```

I passed in the `args.input_file.buffer` data directly, assuming that `args.input` is the `TextIOWrapper` instance that decodes the stdin bytes, and `.buffer` is the underlying `BufferedReader` instance providing the raw binary data. There is no point in decoding this data as Latin-1, then encoding as Latin-1 again. Just pass the bytes on.

Comment: Thank you, @Martijn Pieters this was really helpful. I was distracted by so many different attempts, that I missed this fairly obvious mistake. I also had avro-python3 1.8.2 installed. I made some modifications to the source code for debug purposes, which may have caused some of those distractions. I also reinstalled that, and with your fix, it is working. Thank you again!